# ng2-bootstrap, call Modal defined in child component from parent compent

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, bootstrap-modal, ng2-bootstrap

I am using [ng2-bootstrap](http://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/modals) for the modal stuff.

I am trying to separate my modals and my other components apart. So I have the following files:

***addPlaylist.modal.ts***

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/common';


import {MODAL_DIRECTVES, BS_VIEW_PROVIDERS} from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'addplaylist-modal',
  directives: [MODAL_DIRECTVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES],
  viewProviders: [BS_VIEW_PROVIDERS],
  templateUrl: 'app/channel/modals/addPlaylistModal.html'
})

export class AddPlaylistModalComponent {
  constructor() {
    console.log(this);
  }
}
```

***addPlaylistModal.html***

```
<div bsModal #lgModal="bs-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" (click)="lgModal.hide()" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Large modal</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In it's parent component's html I have code piece like this:

```
  <a (click)="lgModal.show()"><span class="bigplus pull-right"></span></a>
   //some other code
  <addplaylist-modal></addplaylist-modal>
```

This is the parent component:
***channel.component.ts***

```
import { AddPlaylistModalComponent } from './shared/addPlaylist.modal';

@Component({
  selector: 'channel',
  styleUrls: ['app/channel/channel.css'],
  directives: [PlatformsComponent, PagesComponent, PlaylistComponent, VideosComponent, AddPlaylistModalComponent],
  providers: [PlatformService],
  templateUrl: 'app/channel/channel.html'
})
```

What I want to do, I want to be able to let the parent componet to access it and open the modal even if I write the (click)="lgModal.show()" at parent component.

Now if I click the   `<a (click)="lgModal.show()"><span class="bigplus pull-right"></span></a>` , it will say “ can not read property show of undefined"

So, how to let the parent component know that the lgModal is defined and it's in its child component.

Answer (score 11):

Your solution might look something like this:

**ChildComponent**

```
@Component({
  ...
  exportAs: 'child'  <== add this line
})
export class AddPlaylistModalComponent {
  @ViewChild('lgModal') lgModal; <== reference to Modal directive
  show(){   <== public method
    this.lgModal.show(); 
  }
}
```

**ParentComponent**

```
template: `<a class="btn btn-success" (click)="c.show()">Add</a>
           <addplaylist-modal #c="child"></addplaylist-modal>`
```

See also the completed sample here https://plnkr.co/edit/2UAB7lpqqAvchTsLwzr6?p=preview

Comment: I'm getting `platform-browser.umd.js:2306 EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentInjector' of undefined`

Comment: How does the line `this.viewContainerRef = viewContainerRef;` working in the example you have provided. The class App doesn't have a property or member named viewContainerRef

Comment: @Pritesh Acharya It's the same as `private viewContainer` within constructor https://plnkr.co/edit/jjmPvd7kue8PB8Xzs6Ij?p=preview. Look at this documentation https://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/modals (Don't forget to add hack to your application root component)

Comment: AFAIK in the previous example `this.viewContainerRef = viewContainerRef;` should throw compile error because it's don't have public, private or protected modifier in the constructor.

Comment: @yurzui  Plunker doesn't work, but I looking at the code in plunker I was able to get mine working! Up voted of course.